# Javascript promises error says that .then() is not defined. Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

This is probably a simple question with a simple answer, but I am not very experienced with this sort of stuff. It is saying that .then() is not defined in this code. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```js
const Mypromise = num => { 
  new Promise( function(resolve, reject) { if (num === 0) {
   resolve('Zero was inputted')
 } else
   {
     reject('You put in a number other than zero')
     
   }})

 }  

// const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() *2)
const handleSuccess = handleResolve => {console.log(handleResolve)};
const handleFailure = handleReject => {console.log(handleReject);}

Mypromise(5 ).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleFailure);
```

The error will be seen when you run the code snippet. Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` your `Promise`, otherwise, you're returning `undefined` (which doesn't have a property/function called `then`).

```js
const Mypromise = num => {
  // return the Promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (num === 0) {
      resolve('Zero was inputted')
    } else {
      reject('You put in a number other than zero')

    }
  })

}

// const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() *2)
const handleSuccess = handleResolve => {
  console.log(handleResolve)
};
const handleFailure = handleReject => {
  console.log(handleReject);
}

Mypromise(5).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleFailure);
```